# Imposible grant privileges from java to MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql-grant

I'm desperate! Scenario: a MySql database and a Java program from where I do some stuff in that database. So far so good. 
I'm now trying to create a new user (which I can) and set password for that same user (which I can too). Problem is when I try to Grant some privileges to that user. I use this query

```
 GRANT SELECT ON respet.some_table TO 'ro'@'localholst'
```

The answer is Error Code: 1133. Can't find any matching row in the user table.
So I checked with

```
 SELECT * FROM mysql.user
```

And it shows that there is the user

```
 'localhost', 'ro', '*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF'
```

I have read a lot about use FLUSH PRIVILEGES but It doesn't work either.

Then I tried that query

```
GRANT SELECT ON respet.some_table TO 'ro'@'localholst' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

And aparently works, but It's a lie, when I do, because I do

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ro'@'localhost'
```

All that It returns is

```
'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'ro\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF\''
```

So, I don't have a clue about what's happening. In case you're wondering, that's the query I'm using to create the user from Java

```
"CREATE USER '" + userName + "'@'localhost'";
```

That's for set password

```
"SET PASSWORD FOR '" + userName + "'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('" + password + "')";
```

And you now the rest. Funny thing is, If I create the user from Workbench, It all works but the Grant privileges part. any clues? thanks!

Comment: Your `grant` statements specify "localholst" where I think you mean "localhost" (your grants have an extra "l" character). If the text in your question is the actual text you are using, that would explain your problem.

Comment: O.M.G. you're right. Code in java was mistaking and all this time I was looking to code in Workbench. Thank you Rob. I will use your name as my DB test user from now on. Thanks

Comment: "I will use your name as my DB test user from now on" -Brilliant, I now dream that one day someone will give me this honour